# How to Show the title of Tabbar item only on selection rest tabbar item will no title in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using native UITabBarController and my requirement is to show the title of TabBar item only on selection and rest of titles will be disappear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each of your viewControllers you can call a function in viewDidLoad that does this

```
public func removeTitle(){

        if let tab = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items, let currentTab = self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController {
            tab.forEach {
                if currentTab != self {
                    $0.title = ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your viewDidLoad:

```
viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()
removeTitle()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Slide modification to @Michael Wells answers

```
public func removeTitle(){
    if let tab = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items  {
        for (index, element) in tab.enumerated() {
            if index == 0{
                element.title = "Home"
            }else{
                element.title = ""
            }
        }
        
        }
    }
```

and instead of calling it on viewDidLoad you should call it on viewDidAppear

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    removeTitle()
}
```

here we are using index of bottom navigation {0,1,2} = {Home,Notices,Profile}

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Tabbar class like:

```
class CustomTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Setbackground Color
    self.tabBar.barTintColor = _WHITE_COLOR

    viewDidLoadOps()
}

func viewDidLoadOps() ->Void {
    let tab1 =   self.tabBar.items![0]
    let tab2 =   self.tabBar.items![1]

    setTabBarItem(tab1, "normal_image_name", "selected_image_name", "your_title", 1)
    setTabBarItem(tab2, "normal_image_name", "selected_image_name", "your_title", 2)

    //For normal state, the color is clear color, so you will not see any title until your tab is selected.    
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for:.normal)

    //Set any color for selected state  
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for:.selected)
}

func setTabBarItem(_ tabBarItem: UITabBarItem, _ noramlImageName: String, _ selectedImageName: String, _ title: String, _ tag: Int) -> Void {
    tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: noramlImageName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: selectedImageName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    tabBarItem.title = title
    tabBarItem.tag = tag
}

}
```

Please comment if you have any questions.

Happy to help!